# How to create system configuration for fileds of the custom table which is imports that fields using csv via import in admin configuration? Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, import, custom-field

I have created the module to import CSV to a custom table. the columns of table should dynamically be added to the import.xml and not by code to import the CSV and not by code.in Magento 2
for example, I am using sales order table columns in

> customImport.php

```
const state = 'state';
    const status = 'status';
    const coupon_code = 'coupon_code';
    const protect_code = 'protect_code';
    const shipping_description = 'shipping_description';
    const is_virtual = 'is_virtual';
    const store_id = 'store_id'; 
    const customer_id = 'customer_id'; 
    const base_discount_amount = 'base_discount_amount';
    const base_discount_canceled = 'base_discount_canceled';
    const base_discount_invoiced = 'base_discount_invoiced';
```

and more..
these fields i have to add in system configuration to import in copy of legacy_order table

Comment: For Magento 1 or Magento 2 ?

Comment: for magento 2.3

Comment: Do you mean you need to show the custom table values in Stores -> configuration? If yes then what will be the name of the fields values of the fields?

Comment: yes,i edited the question with fields,i have to add all 130column fields of sales_order table

Comment: what is your custom table structure and CSV structure?

Comment: same as sales_order table structure and csv file of sales_order table,i have just created db_schema.xml to create same table as sale_order.and imported the the csv file of sales_order into another table legacy_order.